# use htaccess to prevent calling page except with RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to use .htaccess to prevent a page from being served unless it is by a rewrite rule?
for example I have clean URLS so a call to `xyz.com/hi` serves `xyz.com/hi.php`.

I would like to achieve if the called url = `xyz.com/hi.php` that the page `opps.html` gets served, but the normal `xyz.com/hi` still works.

thx Art

```
DirectoryIndex h1.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# stop calling page by ext
RewriteRule .*\.(php)$ opps.html [L]

# main start page
RewriteRule ^hi$ hi.php [L]
```

Comment: Your issue is that once `hi` becomes `hi.php`, a **new** request for `hi.php` is given to the server. So then your `.htaccess` will see the request for `hi.php` and redirect to `opps.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a condition to prevent php extensions from getting rewritten to `oops.html`. If you want to prevent actual requests for php pages, you can use the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable inside a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.php\ 
RewriteRule .*\.(php)$ opps.html [L]
```

This way, internally re-written URI's that end with `.php` won't get rewritten to `oops.html`.

Comment: thx for the suggestion, however this gives me `RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters`. I have tried as the first & last rule in the .htaccess file. Thx Art

Comment: Looks like it was a FTP error with cut'n'paste, writing it out manually works a treat, thx @JonLin